# How to make a Table without an @Id Column?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Here's I've got 2 main independant tables, `user` & `detail`, and a 3rd one that link each other `users_details` with two foreign keys as follow:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| detail_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

To implement this in Spring Data JPA, I'm using this class which displays the error `Persistent entity 'UsersDetails' should have primary key`:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_details")
public class UsersDetails {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "detail_id")
    private Detail detail;
}
```

Since I don't have any primary key, how should I bypass this?

Or, should I make one even if it's not used?

Comment: You should either add an `@id` column to your JPA entity, or make the combination of the `user_id` and `detail_id` the primary key of this table/entity.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks to you!

Comment: The composite key option is fairly ugly...I've never done it myself, and I often tend to just add an auto increment column to the entity, which is easy to do.

Comment: Although it's ugly to use composite keys, it can be necessary to use them, when due to performance reasons having a key under a table is not allowed, or you want to map a database view to java via JPA, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to map the table `users_details`. You can let JPA manage it automatically by defining a many-to-many relationship.

You can see a couple of examples [here](https://github.com/augusto/jpa-workshop/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ig/training/hibernate/domainmodel) in case you want to map it unidirectionally or bidirectionally.

If you do want to map it for whatever reason, the way to map it is to make a composite key with both values (the typical way to design a many-to-many relationship table). All JPA entities *must* have an id, so you cannot avoid not having an id. The repo above has an example of a composite key. You'll need to annotate the fields with `@Id` and provide a Composite key class with `@IdClass`.

Comment: Thank you sir immensely for the great resource and explanation!